# Keep moving div inside browser area using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a moving div on my webpage that uses the mouseover with pagex and pagey and jquery animate function and then changes the top and left values. As it moves it will go past the browser size and start to scroll. How can I keep it in the confines of the browser and not scroll?

Comment: show us what you have done so far

Comment: you can create a boundary using using the size of the moved element and the window height and widht

Comment: How do I get the size of the moved element?

Comment: without seeing what you have done we won't be able to help much

Comment: The basic formula for x-axis will be something like `if(window.width < mouse.x + el.width) { do not move further}`

Comment: Work out the dimensions of browser window and keep the top and left values within that boundary. Have you got the code? paste into a jsfiddle.net